# Timeout happens instantly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf

My setup as follows

- MVC ASP.net Web application
- WCF Services (Called via ajax)
- SQL Database

I have the timeout values set to 1 minute and this is working fine most of the time. However, intermittently, when a user makes a request, a timeout error is thrown. This happens instantly (less than a second!)

I've managed to locate the timeout to be between WCF and SQL but I don't understand why its not waiting a minute.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Error message - Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: What kind of timeout is it? it can be a wcf session timeout. (10 mins by default if i remember correctly)

Comment: What is your exact error message?

Comment: Can you please give the exact error if possible stack trace? Some code will also help.

Comment: set the ajax timeout settings while calling the WCF services.

Comment: I've added the error message. Since the timeout is happening almost instantly I was leaning towards the "Server is not responding" part of the exception.